# HTML grid layout of multiple app does not work

Tags: html, angular

I am new to html, and have trouble in grid layout. I'd like to display 4 app in the way that app1,app2 and app3 in the first row, and app4 in the second row. The code is attached as below. However, app1/2/3 are crowd together in the layout. Did I miss anything there?

All app are like

```
<div class="container">
    here are some code
</div>
```

Here is the code for the grid:

```
<style>
  .queryInner {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "query patientImage cohortImage",  "result result result";
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    align-items: start;
  }
</style>

<div class ="queryInner">
  <div [style.grid-area] = "'query'">
    <app-genotype-query></app-genotype-query>
  </div>

  <div [style.grid-area] = "'patientImage'">
    <app-individual-image></app-individual-image>
  </div>

  <div [style.grid-area] = "'cohortImage'">
    <app-cohort-image></app-cohort-image>
  </div>

  <div [style.grid-area] = "'result'">
    <app-genotype-query-list></app-genotype-query-list>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the comma

```
grid-template-areas: "query patientImage cohortImage"
                         "result result result";
```